# Ruby returns early from loop

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.6

I have a class, with one method:

```
class ScreenerProbe 
  def initialize
    @body = {}
  end

  def import_simple_matrix(questions, answers)    
    @body['aliases'] = answers.map { |pair| 
      return { val: pair["text"], text: pair["value"] }
    }
    
    # this code doesn't seem to run
    questions.each.with_index do |text, index|
      @body["questions"][index + 1] = {
        "title" => text,
        "type" => 'default',
      }
    end
end
```

The problem is that some of the code doesn't seem to run, even though I expect it to.

**ruby 2.6.6p146 (2020-03-31 revision 67876) [x86_64-darwin20]**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling `return` from inside a loop, it won't only "exit" the loop, you will return from the outer method, in this case `import_simple_matrix`.

This is probably not what you want, and the reason why some assignments, that you're expecting, won't occur.

Comment: To actually `return` from a block, and not a whole def, you can use a directive `next`. In this example it's enough to just skip the `return` part though.